# Open a workbook from Saved location

Tags: vba, excel, savechanges

Have a requirement to store a file in mydocuments. Save location has to be VDI or laptop independent.

I am able to successfully save the file, in the location I want. But with the same file name and location, I am unable to open it.

The path and the filename for workbooks.open is coming like this, when I am testing it thru VDI. Bit strange, I not able to open the workbook using the path I used to save it.

"\xxx.yyy.CO.NZ\PaleeS.home$\InsuranceAdvisory\Excel\DT_test delete_rectangle 1_04.May.17.xlsm"

```
Dim strFilename As String
Dim Client1 As Range
Dim Client2 As Range
Dim CurrentDate As String
Dim FilePrefix As String
Dim strDir As String
Dim StrDirSub As String
Dim Savedflie As String
Dim CurrentFolderpath As String
Dim CurrentFilename As String

CurrentFolderpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
CurrentFilename = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

strDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("mydocuments") & Application.PathSeparator & "\InsuranceAdvisory"
StrDirSub = strDir & "\Excel"
If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir strDir
End If
Select Case Dir(StrDirSub, vbDirectory)
    Case ""
    MkDir StrDirSub
End Select
FilePrefix = "\DT_"
Set Client1 = Range("Client1")
Set Client2 = Range("Client2")
CurrentDate = Format(Date, "dd.mmm.yy")
strFilename = FilePrefix & Client1.Value & "_" & Client2.Value & "_" & CurrentDate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs StrDirSub & strFilename & ".xlsm"
Savedflie = StrDirSub & strFilename & ".xlsm"
Application.Workbooks.Open (Savedflie)
```

Comment: The code crashes for me as it tries to **save** the file.  Removing the extra "\" from `Application.PathSeparator & "\InsuranceAdvisory"` allowed the code to successfully save and open the file.  (Which is strange, because I have never known a "\\" instead of "\" to cause problems before. But that might be because it is using a UNC path rather than just a "local" path.)

Comment: Working a bit differently for me. While saving addition "\" allows to save the file successfully. But when re opening the file, I either have to remove APplication.PathSeperater or "\". But, for now it use two different path + or - "\" for saving and opening. Thanks for the inputs mate.